# Invalid schema configuration ---mongoose

Tags: mongoose

[Image of Code with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3inUy.jpg)

I wrote the below schema. But while running it gives me an error     throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${path}` schematype definition is ` + --- can someone help me why does this error comes?. Below shown is my schema, can someone figure out if my schema have some mistakes.

Comment: Please post your code as formatted code instead of an image to stop your question being closed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you are creating a local variable `boolean` via you `require` function and then using it as the type for your `active` property here:

```js
const { boolean } = require("webidl-conversions") //< Create boolean variable

const playlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   //...
   active: boolean //<< Using it here
})
```

You can fix this by setting the type of your `active` property to `Boolean` as per the mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#booleans).

```js
const playlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   //...
   active: Boolean //<< Change this
})
```

I'm not familiar with the `webidl-conversions` library but it's likely that the value of `boolean` imported is a function or an object and mongoose is expecting a `Boolean`.